# Find all $n$ such that $\varphi(n)=20$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

> How can I find all integers such that $\varphi(n)=20$, where $\varphi$ is the Euler-totient function

I've seen somewhere that $\varphi(n)\ge\sqrt{n}$, for all  $n$ except $n=2$ and $n=6$, without proof (and I think the proof is quite challenging). Is there an elementary way to find it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all solutions to $\phi(x)=20$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3406553/find-all-solutions-to-phix-20)

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

If $n=\prod_{r=1}^mp_r^{u_r},\phi(n)=\prod_{r=1}^mp_r^{u_r-1}(p_r-1)$ for $u_r\ge1\forall r$

So, for each prime $p_r$ that divides $n,p_r-1$ must divide $20$

Comment: $n=\prod_{r=1}^n$ or $n=\prod_{r=1}^m$ ?

Comment: Matt is right,you don't have to have $n$ divisors,you can have it only when $n=2$ so the upper limit should be a arbitrary number $m$.

Comment: @kingW3, I meant the current version

Comment: @MattAllegro, I meant $m$(independent of $n$) divisors

Answer (score 0):

To work this out, you would note that the Eule phi function is weakly multiplicative, that is, f(ab) = f(a) f(b), only if a, b have no common divisors.

So it is a matter of going through the various prime and prime-powers, for numbers that divide N=20, eg

```
 2 (1) 4 (2)  8 (4)       16 (8)
 3 (2)                     9 (6)
 5 (4) 25 (20)            125 (100)
                           7   (6)
 11 (10)                  121 (110)
```

You then work out what numbers multiply to N, by working from the end

```
 11 (10)      (2) comes from 3, 2*3 and 4
 25 (20)      (1) comes from 1 and 2
```

None of the numbers against 2 or 3 are multiples of 5, so this is complete

```
 20:  33, 44, 50, 25, 66
```