# Find all solutions to $\phi(x)=20$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find all solutions to $\phi(x)=20$

I know that $1,2,4,5,10,20$ all divide $20$ and that $20=5\cdot 2^2$

and $1,2,4,10$ are integers so that $x+1$ is a prime.

I can see that $25$ is a solution since $25=5^2$ and $\phi(25)=5(4)=20$

But I'm not sure how to get any other solutions, if there are any.

Comment: Do you know the formula for $\phi(x)$?

Comment: Which formula? $\phi(x)=x\prod_{p\vert x}(1-1/p)$?

Comment: If $p\mid x$ then $(p-1)\mid 20$.

Comment: some multiples of $11$ are solutions

Comment: If $n$ is odd, then $\phi(2n)=\phi(n)$.

Comment: If $x=\prod p_i^{a_i}$ then $\phi (x)=\prod (p_i-1)\cdot p_i^{a_i-1}=20=5\cdot2^2$. After that, it's just looking at combinations of divisors of $20$ and parsing them into $p_i-1$ and $p_i^{a_i-1}$, then working back to identify $x$.

Comment: Ok so the only prime divisors I have for $x$ are $2,3,5,11$. And I know that if $x$ is odd, then it must be divisible by $3$ since $\phi(x)$ is divisible by $2$.

Comment: But $25$ isn't divisible by $3$.

Comment: Ok well. I can see that 33 also works. But I'm still not sure how I can narrow down the number of solutions at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\phi(x) = 20$, then it is clear that $x$ only contains prime divisors $p$ such that $p - 1$ is a divisor of $20$.

Therefore the prime divisors of $x$ can only be: $2, 3, 5, 11$.

If a prime power $p^r$ divides $x$ with $r > 1$, then $p^{r - 1}$ must divide $\phi(x)$. Therefore only $2$ and $5$ can appear multiple times in the factorisation of $x$, and the maximal powers are $2^3$ and $5^2$ respectively.

---

In short, all possible $x$ are divisors of $2^3 \times 3 \times 5^2 \times 11$.

Listing all possibilities, we get the whole list: $25, 33, 44, 50, 66$.